# replace dictionary values with list of values

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is my dictionary
dict_1:

```
{'ABC1': None, 'BBC2': None, 'PPP13': None, '1FGEE':None, 'STUFF':None, 'LUB23':None, 'UNIT44':None, 'ZX3454F2':None, 'AMS76':None, 'LLPT43':None}
```

I'm trying to replace the values with strings in a list:

list_info:

```
['ABC1-99.txt', 'BBC2-qp.txt', 'PPP13-jj5.txt', 'PPP13-frr.txt', '1FGEE-oop2.txt', 'STUFF-34534.txt', 'LUB23-j873.txt', 'UNIT44-oi5.txt', 'ZX3454F2-k.txt', UNIT44-de3t.txt, 'AMS76-light.txt', 'LLPT43-ifg.txt']
```

Desired output:

```
{'ABC1':['ABC1-99.txt'], 'BBC2':['BBC2-qp.txt'], 'PPP13':['PPP13-jj5.txt', 'PPP13-frr.txt'], 
'1FGEE':['1FGEE-oop2.txt'], 'UNIT44':['UNIT44-oi5.txt','UNIT44-de3t.txt'], ...}
```

I have tested this with the code:

```
new_dict = dict((i,j) for i,j in dict_1.items() if j in [n.split('-', 1)[0] for n in list_info])
```

still can't get it correct
:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a new dict with the same keys as dict_1. and every value is a list containing all file names that start with the key.

```
dict_1 = {'ABC1': None, 'BBC2': None, 'PPP13': None, '1FGEE':None, 'STUFF':None, 'LUB23':None, 'UNIT44':None, 'ZX3454F2':None, 'AMS76':None, 'LLPT43':None}
list_info = ['ABC1-99.txt', 'BBC2-qp.txt', 'PPP13-jj5.txt', 'PPP13-frr.txt', '1FGEE-oop2.txt', 'STUFF-34534.txt', 'LUB23-j873.txt', 'UNIT44-oi5.txt', 'ZX3454F2-k.txt', 'UNIT44-de3t.txt', 'AMS76-light.txt', 'LLPT43-ifg.txt']

new_dict = {k: [fname for fname in list_info if fname.startswith(k)] for k in dict_1}
print(new_dict)

# if you need to modify dict_1 in place
dict_1.update(new_dict)
```

```
{'ABC1': ['ABC1-99.txt'], 'BBC2': ['BBC2-qp.txt'], 'PPP13': ['PPP13-jj5.txt', 'PPP13-frr.txt'], '1FGEE': ['1FGEE-oop2.txt'], 'STUFF': ['STUFF-34534.txt'], 'LUB23': ['LUB23-j873.txt'], 'UNIT44': ['UNIT44-oi5.txt', 'UNIT44-de3t.txt'], 'ZX3454F2': ['ZX3454F2-k.txt'], 'AMS76': ['AMS76-light.txt'], 'LLPT43': ['LLPT43-ifg.txt']}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {}
for s in list_info:
    key = s.split('-')[0]
    d.setdefault(key, []).append(s)
```

As `d` has the desired data, you don't really need the `dict_1` with the `None` values, but you can update it with the new dictionary, if you wanted:

```
dict_1.update(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
dictionary = {'ABC1': None, 'BBC2': None, 'PPP13': None, '1FGEE':None, 'STUFF':None, 'LUB23':None, 'UNIT44':None, 'ZX3454F2':None, 'AMS76':None, 'LLPT43':None}
txtlist = ['ABC1-99.txt', 'BBC2-qp.txt', 'PPP13-jj5.txt', 'PPP13-frr.txt', '1FGEE-oop2.txt', 'STUFF-34534.txt', 'LUB23-j873.txt', 'UNIT44-oi5.txt', 'ZX3454F2-k.txt', 'UNIT44-de3t.txt', 'AMS76-light.txt', 'LLPT43-ifg.txt']
res = list(dictionary.keys())
for i in range(len(res)): 
    dictionary[res[i]] = txtlist[i]
print(dictionary)
```